# Count returns the count of all joined data instead of the main object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm trying to count users who have dogs.

```
User.joins(:pets).where("pets.type = ?", :dog).count
```

This returns the count of the users + their dogs combined, instead i just want the count of actual users.

What am i doing wrong?

### Update

I've also tried to just fetch the users using the above query and it returns an array of the same users repeated multiple times depending on how many dogs they have.

Comment: Why can't you do that on the pets model? i.e: `Pet.where(type: 'dog').count`

Comment: @Amir Users can have multiple dogs, Also i need the users anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
User.joins(:pets).where("pets.type = ?", :dog).count(distinct: true)
```

See [api doc](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html#method-i-count).

Comment: That works, but what's the fix if i want to fetch the users not count, which actually prints repeated users?

Comment: Hmm, that didn't seem to do anything, It added `DISTINCT` after `SELECT` but it still fetches repeated users.

Comment: Really? Can you paste the SQL?

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT 'users'.* FROM 'users' INNER JOIN 'pets' ON 'pets'.'user_id' = 'users'.'id' WHERE (pets.type = 'dog')`

Comment: Sorry, I cannot see any reason that this SQL doesn't work. You can try it with a db client if you want.

Comment: The select is correct, as in the SELECT fields you just have users fields the DISTINCT will not let they be repeated. That is why the query is working @ryan.

Answer (score 0):

The joins would return all the duplicate rows for which the user has multiple associations...

For example if a user, U1 has one dog and user, U2 has two dogs then total three rows would be returned by the joins....so instead of using joins, try to use the includes option...

refer to this Railscast, http://railscasts.com/episodes/181-include-vs-joins for more...

Comment: Thanks, includes works perfectly but i think fetching dogs too is memory wasteful :/